# Heroku sets SECRET_KEY_BASE when it's not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want Heroku to not set `SECRET_KEY_BASE` so I can use the one from credentials, but despite me deleting it from the UI, verifying it doesn't exist by running `heroku config`, I still get it set as an environment variable on my dynos. And it's the same in all the dynos:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=d2753b472abb...
```

I also tried setting it to a blank string by running `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=""` and Heroku insist on setting it up as I can see by running bash and then `env` within bash.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: I am also experiencing this. It is very frustrating to say the least. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Heroku Ruby buildpack generates and sets `SECRET_KEY_BASE` via the shell if it doesn't exist in your Heroku config vars.

It currently doesn't seem possible to directly use the secret key set in `credentials.yml`. You could make `credentials.yml` and `SECRET_KEY_BASE` align though.

Source: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/1143

And here is a short extract from that issue:

> - If you set your own SECRET_KEY_BASE, we do nothing.
> - If you do not set a SECRET_KEY_BASE we generate and set one for you.
> - We recommend using our heroku config interface for storing secrets rather than using the encrypted file storage that ships with rails.
> - If you want to use encrypted file storage locally with rails you could copy our secret key base `heroku run echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` or you can set your own
>   value manually locally and then again via heroku config.